# Dynamic Linq for SQL MIN() function

Tags: sql, linq, dynamic-linq

Original SQL looks like:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS GeoID, MIN(PostalCode), PlaceName
    FROM GeoData_ALL
    GROUP BY CountryCode, PlaceName
    ORDER BY PlaceName
```

I need to translate it in Dynamic Linq, something like:

```
var searchResult = db.Set(GeoData)
    .AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy("PlaceName")
    .GroupBy("CountryCode", "PlaceName")
    .Select("new (MIN(ID) AS GeoID, MIN(PostalCode), PlaceName");
```

Unfortunately 'MIN' function doesn't seem applicable to Dynamic Linq

Answer (score 0):

Following code can help, please check (this is a sample code only):

```
var searchResult = db.Set(GeoData)
    .AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy("PlaceName")
    .GroupBy("CountryCode", "PlaceName")
    .Select(g => new { GeoID = g.Min(p => p.ID), PostalCode = g.Min(p => p.PostalCode), PlaceName = g.PlaceName });
```

Comment: I guess lambda expressions cannot be used this way in Dynamic Linq.
In any case '.Select' is expecting a string as argument.